# Как отправить к REST сервису запрос с InputStream и периодически записывать в него данные

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, веб-служба, jersey

Есть задача: Нужно создать **клиент** и **REST web-сервис на java**.

- Клиент должен сформировать **InputStream** и передать его сервису
  после чего каждые 10 сек (или другой интервал не важно), дописывать в него новые порции данных.
- у сервиса должен быть метод, который принимает в качестве аргумента **InputStream** и выводит полученные данные в лог.

(можно передавать сервису информацию о количестве файлов, которые будут переданы сервису бля того чтобы сервис знал когда можно завершить прием данных)

в идеале стрим должен представлять из себя tar архив, а в виде данных дописываемых 
в стрим должны выступать текстовые файлы..

**PS**: решение должно быть именно на InputStream:

**не подходят:**

- решения на веб сокетах;
- отправка текстовых файлов клинтом отдельными запросами на сервис

Буду благодарен ссылкам, советам, примерам кода..

Comment: условия условиями, но зачем изобретать велосипед? странные люди которые дают такие задания

Comment: `InputStream` это класс в джаве. Передаются данные в виде байтов ибо IS работает с байтами. Вам нужно поднять `Socket` (это не веб сокет) соединение и слать туда все что угодно.

Comment: @Tsyklop, спасибо.. за ответ.  разницу сокета и веб сокета я понимаю... тоже сразу предложил такой вариант... но был ошарашен - "сокеты не использовать"... так же можно посылать кучу файлов по отдельности и балансировщик сам выполнит распределение нагрузки для отдельных инстансов сервиса..  но смысл задания, как мне пояснили, именно в том, чтобы создать стрим из архива .tar и передавть в него файлы...

Comment: А на чем REST будет писаться? имею в виду на Spring? или нет?

Comment: @Tsyklop, да.. предполагается spring boot + jersey.

Comment: Ну... Поднять `IS`. и в вайле считывать байты и писать в открытый `HttpUrlConnection`. После каждого считывания делать `Thread.sleep`.

Comment: @Tsyklop, спасибо. попробую использовать для реализации клиента HttpUrlConnection (я пробовал использовать jersey client)..  Меня смущало в этом подходе, только то, что я передам по сути открытыйй IS...  мне почему-то казалось, что после отправки запроса IS закроется...

Comment: он закроется когда сами его закроете.